# Printing from a list

Tags: python, list, printing

This is an easier question then most.  I'm new to the programming scene and could use some help.  I'm trying to print the text below to a list of names specified by the user.  The error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: GoodDaySir() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

python 3.3

```
mylist=input('Who is visiting today?')
def GoodDaySir():
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        print('Hello to you.')
        print('Have a good day, ', mylist)
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?  If not, could you edit your post to reflect your actual indentation?

Comment: After you fix your indentation, please show us how you are calling `GoodDaySir`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to indent the lines after `def` and `for`:

```
mylist=input('Who is visiting today?')
def GoodDaySir():
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
         print('Hello to you.')
         print('Have a good day, ', mylist)
```

Although I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with this piece of code ;-)

You probably want something like this:

```
def GoodDaySir(visitors):
    """ This function takes a list() of visitors and prints out a greeting
        for each person.
    """
    for person in visitors :
         print('Hello to you.')
         print('Have a good day, ', person)

# Get a list of names separated by ","
visitors = raw_input('Who is visiting today?')

# Convert the string to an actual list()
visitorsList = [x.strip() for x in visitors.split(',')]

# Call our function with the list as parameter and greet the visitors
GoodDaySir(visitorsList)
```

Comment: This might be better off as a comment.

Comment: His issue is probably not indentation or he would be getting a different error.  His issue is likely that he isn't including a parameter variable in his definition, but is supplying a parameter when calling it.

Comment: Yeah, got it… I just added an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: GoodDaySir() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This error means you are passing a parameter to a function that doesn't take one.  You have defined

```
def GoodDaySir():
```

with no parameters.  When you pass `mylist` to `GoodDaySir` it doesn't know what to do with it.  Perhaps change your function to

```
def good_day_sir(people):
    for person in people:
        print('Hello to you.')
        print('Have a good day, ', person)
```

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that you aren't using indentation at all, but it wouldn't work still.

An example of solution may be:

```
def GoodDaySir():
    names = raw_input('Who is visiting today?') #this returns a string of names 
    namesList = names.split(',') #let's suppose that those names are separated by commas

    for name in namesList:
        print('Hello to you.')
        print('Have a good day, ', name)`
```